# how to fixed position of a div for all screen resolutions

Tags: css-position

Problem is that if I browse the application on 1024 x 768 pixels it works great but when i change the resolution up to 1280 x 800 pixels the login table inside the div change its position. I want this to appear same on every resolution...any suggestions or workaround.

CSS:

```
img#bg
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

HTML:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <img src="../../../../Images/LoginBackGround_Image.bmp" alt="BG Image" id="bg" />
        <div style="position: relative">

        <div style="position: absolute; margin-top:30%; margin-left:70%; 
               border: 1px solid #0570E3; z-index: 1;">    
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                     /td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
         </table>

        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I've tried a lot of things but it’s not working for all screen resolution.

Comment: Have you tried making it a [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) of `#form1` instead?